# How to re-route my Streamlit app that's been deployed to my Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, router, streamlit

### Issue re-routing Kubernetes deployed app

Hi, we've deployed a Streamlit app on our Kubernetes cluster with no problem: the app loads using the correct URL. Now we want to expose this app outside of our working environment, and for this we plan on using a router using the IHttpHandler class (see code bellow). Our problem is that the page is partially loading, but all the rendering is not done.

Here's the code that we're using:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        HttpRequest original = context.Request;

        string service = "our_url";

        HttpWebResponse fwResponse = ForwardRequest(context.Request, service);
        if (fwResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            Stream stream = fwResponse.GetResponseStream();
            context.Response.ContentType = fwResponse.ContentType;
            stream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
            return;
        }
       
    }

    public HttpWebResponse ForwardRequest(HttpRequest request, string serviceUri) {
        HttpWebRequest fwRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUri);

        fwRequest.ContentType = request.ContentType;
        fwRequest.Method = request.HttpMethod;
        fwRequest.UserAgent = request.UserAgent;

        if (request.HttpMethod != "GET"
                && request.HttpMethod != "HEAD"
                && request.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            Stream fwStream = fwRequest.GetRequestStream();
            request.InputStream.CopyTo(fwStream);
            fwStream.Close();
        }

        return (HttpWebResponse)fwRequest.GetResponse();
    }
```

Now the issue is that we correctly get the base HTML file for the page but we get an error 404 for the .js and .css files we need to fully render the page (see below).